# Calculate for which a the functions is well defined

Tags: calculus

Calculate the $a$ for which the function is well defined.
\[ \frac{3 \left(\frac{3}{a}-9\right) a^2 \left(25-a^2\right)}{(3 a+15) \left(9 a^2-6 a+1\right)} \]

I simplified the function and my answer is 
\[ \frac{(5-a)(1-3a)}{3a+1}\] and $a$ can't be $-\frac{1}{3}$ but its wrong.

Comment: I count 3 denominators in the original function.  None of those denominators can be allowed to equal zero.

Comment: Find the domain first. Simplify afterwards. Simplifying might affect the domain.

Answer (score 2):

A Function can't be "true" i simplified it to 
\[ \frac{3(a-5) a}{3a-1}\]
so it won't be well defined (I guess this is what you are looking for) when

> \[ a=\frac{1}{3}\]

The question is what your term "true" shall mean, when you accept continuous extensinos the above solution does it. If not you have to look at all terms in your original equation, then

> \[ a=0 \quad a=-5 \quad a=\frac{1}{3} \]

won't be possible.

Comment: @GitGud thanks edited it

Answer (score 0):

Your "picture"
$${3 \left({3\over a}-9\right) a^2 \left(25-a^2\right)}\over{(3 a+15) \left(9 a^2-6 a+1\right)}$$
is not a function, but an *expression* containing a variable $a$. Let us interpret  $a$ as a real variable. This expression is *well-defined* for a particular $a\in{\mathbb R}$ if we can throw it without further explanations at a pocket-calculator and get a certain real number as output, which we then can call a *function value* $f(a)$ for this particular $a$.

As others have pointed out, there are various $a\in{\mathbb R}$ for which the given expression causes an error message. A more careful analysis then shows that for some of these forbidden $a$-values the situation can remedied, insofar as the function $f$ can be extended continuously to these $a$: It is possible to find some other expression which produces the same values as the given one for all allowed $a$, but is well-defined (and continuous) on a slightly larger set.